# FitNesse SVN Version Controller

Tags: git, svn, fitnesse

I have got a requirement to adding version control to [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/) wiki markups we construct.
In older FitNesse version, we have **CMSystem**, which used to provide typical callback methods on several operations on the Test/Suite file that we manipulate like cmUpdate, cmEdit, cmPreDelete, cmDelete.

But in recent version I have observed that [CMSystem is been removed](http://www.fitnesse.org/.FrontPage.FitNesseDevelopment.FitNesseRelease20131110) from the FitNesse library.
Further they have introduced new concept called "VersionController". FitNesse library implicitly providing **GitFileVersionsController** for Git repositories.

But for my requirement I need to implement for SVN.
Can anybody assist with any solution?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? A pointer to something that someone has written (off topic for Stack Overflow)? Help in getting started with writing your own interface (a very broad topic)? Someone to write the whole thing (even more broad)?

Comment: Well, Sorry for the confusion created, I have gone through [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.fitnesse/fitnesse/20131109/fitnesse/wiki/fs/GitFileVersionsController.java?av=f). I couldn't quite understand where to start with. I need a hint if someone have already gone though this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to crack the solution eventually by analyzing the code deeper and finding the socket points to build my own system similar to GitVersionController.

Thanks.